# Format string height

Tags: строки, текст, format

Есть список строк взятый из файла:

```
data = ["Это текст имеет 27 символов", "Этот 16 символов", "а этот и сразу содержит 35 символов"]
```

Задача состоим втом чтобы отформатировать текст таким образом чтобы строка была растянута по ширине, заданной в count.

```
count = int(input())
out = []
for i in data:
    out.append(i.center(35))
print(out)
```

При таком коде я получаю:

```
      Это текст имеет 27 символов   
            Этот 16 символов
```

А хочу получать:

```
Это   текст   имеет   27   символов
Этот           16          символов
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем список `space_index` с индексом каждого пробела в строке.

```
space_index = [index for index, char in enumerate(text) if char == ' ']
```

В строке, рядом с индексом пробела `space_index[i]` добавляем новый пробел.

```
text = text[:space_index[i]] + ' ' + text[space_index[i]:]
```

Изменяем список с индексом пробелов, так как тест изменился.

```
space_index = space_index[:i]+list(map(lambda x: x+1, space_index[i:]))
```

Выполняем это пока строка не станет длинной в 35 символов.

```
def my_func(data, count=35):
    for text in data:
        space_index = [index for index, char in enumerate(text) if char == ' ']
        i = 0
        while True:
            if len(text) < count and len(space_index) > 0:
                text = text[:space_index[i]] + ' ' + text[space_index[i]:]
                space_index = space_index[:i]+list(map(lambda x: x+1, space_index[i:]))
                i+=1
                if i+1 > len(space_index):
                    i = 0
            else:
                break
        print(text)

data = ["Это текст имеет 27 символов", "Этот 16 символов", "а этот и сразу содержит 35 символов", "aaaaaaaa"]
my_func(data, 35)
```

Ответ:

```
Это   текст   имеет   27   символов
Этот           16          символов
а этот и сразу содержит 35 символов
aaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Все прекрасно, но может есть соображения как организовать без try…except?

Comment: Дополнил: без try…except

Comment: Проблемы данной реализации алгоритма: 1) Не равномерно распределяет пробелы (для данного подхода *(с одного конца пробелы длиннее чем с другого)* есть более простой алгоритм вообще безо всяких циклов, просто на split и join). 2) На входной строке длиннее 35 - уйдёт в бесконечный цикл. 3) Если строка не содержит пробелов - свалится с ошибкой.

Comment: @GrAnd, я понимаю что алгоритм не идеальный, я его делал только что бы проверить себя (как быстро я смогу решить проблему). Только, не особо понимаю что значит "Не равномерно распределяет пробелы (с одного конца пробелы длиннее чем с другого)", он добавляет пробелы по очереди, если число пробелов не четное, в любом случае с одного конца будет на один пробел больше. Для строки "Этот 16 символов" ,будет добавлено 19 пробелов, значит с одной стороны будет 10 а с другой 9 пробелов. Как я и говорил что мой код не идеальный, но 2 и 3 можно решить одним if'ом.

Comment: @Рамис Ну, к примеру, надо разместить 25 пробелов в 7 промежутках. Мой алгоритм разместит их так: [4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], а ваш так: [4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]. Но это мелочь, хотя такой подход можно реализовать без циклов, что сильно ускорит выполнение.

Comment: @Drelar Замените в выражении `if len(text) != 35:` знак сравнения на `<` - бесконечный цикл уйдёт.

Comment: @GrAnd, исправил)

Comment: Крэш на строках без пробелов - остался.

Comment: @GrAnd, исправил)

Comment: @Рамис А я добавил в свой ответ как может выглядеть ваш подход без использования циклов и постоянного модифицирования строк и списков. :)

Comment: @GrAnd, так бы я точно не смог), ваши решения идеальны ++++

Answer (score 2):

Разбить строку на слова, подсчитать требуемое количество пробелов в каждом промежутке, слить слова с пробелами. Profit.

```
def justify(s, maxlen):
    def spaces(l, n): # вычисляет нужное количество пробелов в каждом промежутке
        # l - требуемое общее количество пробелов
        # n - количество мест (промежутков между словами)
        seq = [round(l/n)]
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            seq.append(round(l*i/n) - sum(seq))
        return list(map(lambda x: " "*x, seq))

    s = s.strip()
    if len(s) >= maxlen:
        return s

    words = s.split(" ")
    if len(words) < 2:
        return s.center(maxlen)
    
    return "".join(sum(zip(words, spaces(maxlen - sum(map(len, words)), len(words)-1) + [""]), ()))

data = ["Это текст имеет 27 символов", 
        "Этот 16 символов", 
        "а этот и сразу содержит 35 символов"]
for t in data:
    r = justify(t, 35)
    print(r, "=>", len(r))
```

```
Это   текст   имеет   27   символов => 35
Этот          16           символов => 35
а этот и сразу содержит 35 символов => 35
```

---

Вариант алгоритма как у @Рамис (пробелы распределены не равномерно, а слева больше), но вообще без использования циклов.

```
def justify(s, maxlen):
    s = s.strip()

    if len(s) >= maxlen:
        return s

    space_count = s.count(' ');
    if not space_count:
        return s.center(maxlen)

    total_spaces = maxlen - len(s) + space_count
    min_spaces = total_spaces // space_count

    words  = s.split(' ', round((total_spaces / space_count - min_spaces) * space_count))
    words[-1] = words[-1].replace(' ', ' '*min_spaces)

    return (' '*(min_spaces+1)).join(words)
```